# If statement greater than operation don't work

Tags: java, if-statement

when write the statement to tell the program to break or return, the if statement still executes every time when the condition is not satisfied and cause error :java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

I've tried greater than and equal ==, both worked. And I checked ">" is also an operator in java. Then why it still executes?

```
public class adjacentElementsProduct {

    static int adjacentElementsProduct(int[] inputArray) {
    if(inputArray ==null|| inputArray.length<0) return 0;
    int res=Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for( int i=0; i<inputArray.length;i++){
       int stop=i+1;

       if((i+1) > inputArray.length) break;

       res=Math.max(res,inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

'''

In this case, since '''if((i+1) > inputArray.length) break;'''
doesn't work, so the error message is: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: even if `(i+1)==inputArray.length`, you would get that exception. The highest index you access in an array is `inputArray.length-1`.

Comment: What is max value `i` can take based on `i<inputArray.length` condition? It is `i=inputArray.length-1` and that is also last safe index we can use for `inputArray` (since arrays indexes start from 0). But for that value condition `if((i+1) > inputArray.length) break;` will never be true so you will not execute `break;`. Think it over again, and do you really need that breaking condition? If you want to iterate one time less change `i<inputArray.length` to `i<inputArray.length-1`. BTW `inputArray.length<0` is always false since arrays can't have negative length (empty array has length ==0).

Comment: pls upvote once for me,  my question point is not at the "OfBoundsException", it's in how it works in if((i+1) > inputArray.length) break; I went through the link that he marked mine as duplicated, it didn't answer my question, that's not my question.

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays have zero-based indexing, so the last element in an array of length N is at the (N-1)th element.

EX: `int[] a = {1, 2, 3}`, to access the element 3, we would write `a[2]` or `a[a.length - 1]`.

In your case, your loop will go to `i = inputArray.length - 1`, so if you call `inputArray[i + 1]` you are calling `inputArray[inputArray.length]` which is out of bounds. To avoid this, you can either modify the loop end condition to `i < inputArray.length - 1` or you can change your if statement to be

`if((i+1) >= inputArray.length) break;`.

Comment: very clear when i saw inputArray[inputArray.length].